# Basic usage of multiple constructors with input in java

Tags: java, constructor

I'm having trouble understanding constructors despite researching them, some assistance and explanations would be GREATLY appreciated.

I'm aiming to have the user input a "make" and a "model" for a car, I would like the assignment of input to each variable in a constructor, and later on have three different cars.

How can I properly and efficiently setup a "make" variable that is assigned to user input and can be accessed for display using constructors. This is very basic however I'm having a tough time coding it out.

```
package cartest;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CarTest 
//make, model, year, price, color, size
//default constructor
//property assignment constructor
//enter three diferent cars and display final information
//toString() method and a method to honk the horn
{
    String make;
    String model;
    int year;
    int price;
    String color;
    String size;

    public CarTest()
    {

    }

    void setMake(String make)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a make:");
        make = scanner.nextLine();
    }

    void getMake()
    {
        System.out.println("Selected make: " + make);
    }
    void setModel(String model)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a model:");
        model = scanner.nextLine();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        CarTest carOne = new CarTest(); 
        carOne.getMake();



    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm aiming to have the user input a "make" and a "model" for a car, I
>   would like the assignment of input to each variable in a constructor,
>   and later on have three different cars.

I have modified your class a little bit, like so:

```
class CarTest {
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private int year;
    private int price;
    private String color;
    private String size;

    public CarTest() {
        this.make = "somevalue";
        this.model = "somevalue";
        this.year = 2017;
        this.price = 50000;
        this.color = "somecolor";
        this.size = "somesize";
    }

    public CarTest(String make, String model){
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
    }


    public String getMake() {
       return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
       this.make = make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
       return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
       this.model = model;
    }

    public int getYear() {
       return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
       this.year = year;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
       return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
       this.price = price;
    }

    public String getColor() {
       return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
       this.color = color;
    }

    public String getSize() {
       return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
       this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "CarTest{" +
            "make='" + make + '\'' +
            ", model='" + model + '\'' +
            ", year=" + year +
            ", price=" + price +
            ", color='" + color + '\'' +
            ", size='" + size + '\'' +
            '}';
    }
}
```

as you can see there is a default constructor in which you can specify the default values of the object and also a constructor which takes 2 parameters to allow you to set the `make` and `model` at object construction, you can extend the parameters of course if you deem it necessary.

I would suggest to separate the main method into a different class and have it perform this functionality:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println("Please enter a model:");
      String model = scanner.nextLine(); // validate if you need to
      System.out.println("please enter a make");
      String make = scanner.nextLine();  // validate if you need to
      CarTest carOne = new CarTest(make,model); // pass the entered details to the carOne object
      System.out.println(carOne.getMake()); // will display the value of make that has been entered
}
```

I have done half of this task for you:

```
//make, model, year, price, color, size
//default constructor
//property assignment constructor
//enter three diferent cars and display final information
//toString() method and a method to honk the horn
```

you'll only need to add a few extra code into the solution I have provided and then you're good to go.

Comment: I was wondering if I could assign the carOne.getMake() in the follow line of code to a variable called finalMake or something similar in order to list the components of the car easily in the display such as "Your input car is: honda, civic, 1999, 1000, etc, etc"

 System.out.println(carOne.getMake()); // will display the value of make that has been entered

Comment: @StripelessTiger i have included a toString() method, so all you have to do is System.out.println(carOne); and that will print all the details for it.

Comment: I get a display of "cartest.CarTest@55f96302" how can I properly display this, That'll be my final question, thankyou for the assistance

Comment: @StripelessTiger copy the entire code I have provided and past it as it is. but instead of " System.out.println(carOne.getMake());" do " System.out.println(carOne);"

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println("Please enter a model:");
      String model = scanner.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Please enter a make");
      String make = scanner.nextLine();
      CarTest carOne = new CarTest(make,model); // pass the entered details to the carOne object
      carOne.getMake();
      System.out.println(carOne.getMake()); // will display the value of make that has been entered
      System.out.println(carOne); //displays the entire car
      
}
    
}

Comment: @StripelessTiger did you replace the class "CarTest" with my solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140206/discussion-between-stripeless-tiger-and-ousmane-mahy-diaw).